# How to dynamically control what table a view selects from

Tags: sql-server

Currently I have a single table with a "control" column. The table will usually contain two sets of data, the active set, and the old set. When the data are being updated, the table will contain the active set and the new set. Once the data are updated, the control variable is switched and the new set becomes the active set and the previously active set becomes the old set. Once daily, the old set is deleted and the new set is created. This operation is composed of several intermediary steps that combined normally take a couple of hours. The problem is when the new set of data is being created, selects on the active set will timeout. I have added with(nolock) to those selects, but that didn't seem to help.

To overcome this, my plan now is to have two tables with identical definitions. The active set will be in one table and the old/new set will be in another table. What I'd like to do is have a view that will select data from one table or the other depending on the control value.

My control is a table with an Id column and a progress column. Selects into the table are essentially:

```
SELECT d.* FROM MyData d
JOIN ControlTable c ON c.ID = d.Control
WHERE c.Progress = 1000 -- 1000 is active
```

How would I set up a view to look into one table or another depending on a control? My hope is that I can change MyData from a table to a view so most of my code will not be affected.

Answer (score 2):

Create a synonym.

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.MyData FOR dbo.MyActiveData;
```

Then when you are doing your maintenance or have switched or what have you:

```
DROP SYNONYM dbo.MyData;
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.MyData FOR dbo.MyPassiveData;
```

Now your view can simply reference `dbo.MyData` but that actually redirects to one or the other table conditionally. Note that this isn't really optimizer friendly if the row counts / data fluctuate quite a bit between days.

Comment: The only 'downside' to this would be that each time you (re)create the synonym you need to re-apply security to it. Also, synonyms require quite some hoops when you start querying its meta-data! (sys.columns etc)

Comment: @deroby why would you ever need to apply security to the synonym? Why not just to the underlying tables?

Comment: Does that work ? Going to test it... sounds counter-intuitive.

Comment: nope, doesn't work. Add new user [test], `GRANT SELECT ON dbo.MyPassiveData TO test`, have [test] select from dbo.MyPassiveData : works. CREATE SYNONYM as above, have [test] select from dbo.MyData : The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'MyData', database 'test', schema 'dbo'. In order for [test] to be able to read from the table you have to grant it select rights 'directly' (and they get lost when you drop & recreate the synonym)

Comment: Well that seems like something that's pretty easy to work around - you script it once because it's something you automate, and if you're smart about it, you're not assigning onesy-twosy permissions to a bunch of individual users anyway. In my case the users had SELECT permission on the schema. As for metadata, well, I guess if you are trying to reverse engineer from the definition of the view and have absolutely no clue about the object, then yes, there's an extra step involved. *shrug* Still seems simpler to me than what you proposed.

Comment: I'm not saying that SWITCH is the holy grail but I've used synonyms before and found it to be more annoying to work with than it was worth, you can't even use any of the standard stored procedures on it (sp_help [not really], sp_helpindex, sp_helprotect, etc...) SWITCH allows you to simply transfer the data from one table to another without having to worry about any of the properties of the table like e.g. security; all without making the object 'exotic to work with'. Also, not all client software will recognize MyData as a table and/or be able to pick up its columns for ad-hoc query building.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work ?

```
CREATE VIEW myView
AS
SELECT t.* FROM myTable1 t JOIN myControlTable c ON c.pk = 1 AND c.value = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT t.* FROM myTable2 t JOIN myControlTable c ON c.pk = 1 AND c.value = 2
```

You may have to add WITH (NOLOCK) as 'the other' MyTable might be locked while you're processing it.

Another solution would be to swap the data between both tables. This way you would always have an 'active' table and a 'working' table. 
=> Your 'reporting' always looks at the active table
=> Your 'processing' always looks at the working table

You then use the ALTER TABLE SWITCH command for this. Normally meant to be used for partitioning but I believe it can be used between two identical tables too.

IMHO this would be a much better solution as neither your reporting, nor your processing needs to have 'dynamic' code but always points at the same table.

Some example code to show what I mean:

```
-- cleanup
IF OBJECT_ID('myTable1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE myTable1 
IF OBJECT_ID('myTable2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE myTable2 
IF OBJECT_ID('swapTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE swapTable

GO
-- creat 3 identical tables
CREATE TABLE myTable1 (pk       int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL 
                            CONSTRAINT pkTable1 PRIMARY KEY (pk),
                       value    int     NULL)

CREATE TABLE myTable2 (pk       int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL 
                            CONSTRAINT pkTable2 PRIMARY KEY (pk),
                       value    int     NULL)

CREATE TABLE swapTable (pk       int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL 
                            CONSTRAINT pkSwapTable PRIMARY KEY (pk),
                       value    int     NULL)

-- insert some data
INSERT myTable1 (value) VALUES (123)
INSERT myTable1 (value) VALUES (456)
INSERT myTable2 (value) VALUES (-1)


-- current situation
SELECT info = 'MyTable1', * FROM myTable1
SELECT info = 'MyTable2', * FROM myTable2

-- swap tables around
TRUNCATE TABLE swapTable
ALTER TABLE myTable1 SWITCH TO swapTable

TRUNCATE TABLE myTable1
ALTER TABLE myTable2 SWITCH TO myTable1

TRUNCATE TABLE myTable2
ALTER TABLE swapTable SWITCH TO myTable2 

GO
-- new situation
SELECT info = 'MyTable1', * FROM myTable1
SELECT info = 'MyTable2', * FROM myTable2
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for those who answered.

I didn't find either answer very satisfying so I've been investigating some options. What I've come up with seems reasonable, though I'd like to see comments on it.

First I added a column to contain what table to use to the Control table. Next, I set up a view for the two sets of data (assume two tables: MyData_1 and MyData_2)

```
CREATE VIEW MyData AS
    SELECT d.* FROM MyData_1 d, Control c WHERE c.Progress = 1000 AND c.[Table] = 'MyData_1'
UNION ALL
    SELECT d.* FROM MyData_2 d, Control c WHERE c.Progress = 1000 AND c.[Table] = 'MyData_2'
```

The downside that I see, is that I will need to update all the code that selects the active set from

```
SELECT d.* FROM MyData d
JOIN ControlTable c ON c.ID = d.Control
WHERE c.Progress = 1000 -- 1000 is active
```

to

```
SELECT d.* FROM MyData d
```

This is very similar to @deroby's initial answer. I verified that the query will work when there is a lock on the non-active data set.

Comment: Please, please, please don't use old, dangerous syntax like `FROM t1, t2` - you have a `JOIN` in the question, why are you getting lazy in the answer (which is really the same as @deroby's answer anyway)?

Comment: I don't understand why that is dangerous, but anyway, with two tables, there really is no reason to have a control column anymore, hence there is nothing to join.

Comment: Then why does your view mention two tables? https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins.aspx

Comment: The main reason (IMHO) to use proper the proper syntax over `t1, t2` is that it's easier to spot mistakes, so I'll join (haha) @Aaron on that. Saying that I notice that my code misses the ON-part of the syntax, sigh. I'll see if I can still edit and fix that.

Comment: I used the above solution and it's working well. I did modify the view to use `CROSS JOIN` instead of `t1, t2`